# Communication between Meteor and nodejs apps

Tags: node.js, meteor, faye

I have a Meteor platform with four node apps/servers inside. I'm using seamless iframes to make it look like they are all a whole package while I stay in control, so if one app goes wrong it won't affect the other three nor the platform.

Now, my question is: How to share the same userid between the apps? I can query MongoDB from Node asking for a userid, but how can I query asking for the same userid the online user has in Meteor? One login for everything, that's what I need.

Edit: What about Faye or SimpleBus?

Comment: Did you try this package? https://atmospherejs.com/admithub/shared-auth

Comment: Thanks, but that's for multiple meteor applications and I want to share between Meteor(1 server) and Node(4 servers). If I could just copy and paste my node apps inside meteor project it would be nice, but apparently I have to rewrite them, something I'm not up to.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve it using iframes, they can't interact with your browser so there is no knowing who use it. Maybe jQuery load?

Comment: How can I share a session between both? Meteor is node-powered after all.

Comment: Are the apps all on the same domain? Assuming your Meteor client is the "parent" of all the iframes, you could then get your iframe client to query the parent window to find the current user Id.